# Snakemake does not recognise job failure due to timeout with error code -11

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake, pbs, qsub

Does anyone had a problem snakemake recognizing a timed-out job. I submit jobs to a cluster using `qsub` with a time-out set per rule:

```
snakemake --jobs 29 -k -p --latency-wait 60 --use-envmodules \
--cluster "qsub -l walltime={resources.walltime},nodes=1:ppn={threads},mem={resources.mem_mb}mb"
```

If a job fails within a script, the next one in line will be executed. When a job however hits the time-out defined in a rule, the next job in line is not executed, reducing the total number of jobs run in parallel on the cluster over time. A timed-out job raises according to the MOAB scheduler (PBS server) a `-11` exit status. As far as I understood any [non-zero exit](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-don-t-want-snakemake-to-detect-an-error-if-my-shell-command-exits-with-an-exitcode-1-what-can-i-do) status means failure - or does this only apply to positive integers?!

Thanks in advance for any hint:)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide a `--cluster-status` script, snakemake internally checks job status by touching some hidden files in the submitted job script.  When a job times out, snakemake (on the node) doesn't get a chance to report the failure to the main snakemake instance as qsub will kill it.

You can try a [cluster profile](https://github.com/jaicher/snakemake-qsub) or just grab a suitable [cluster status](https://github.com/jaicher/snakemake-qsub/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.profile_name%7D%7D/qsub-status.py) file (be sure to chmod it as an exe and have qsub report a parsable job id).

Comment: I have seen the [PBS-TORQUE (qsub) "official" profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/pbs-torque) before, but then I got the above code snippet from a college to get started. Thanks for the brief and good explanation!